# centering of div inside body

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
<body>

<div id="maindiv" class="rounded">
something written
</div>

</body>
```

with this css:

```
body {
background-image: url('stjohnhusimages/green gradient.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:1024px;
height:1375px;
background-size: cover;
text-align:center;
}

#maindiv {
width:900px;
height:1275px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 40px;
background-color:#404853;
}
```

but the main div is still getting aligned to the left.  Wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It doesn't look like it is, http://jsfiddle.net/tqT6W/ Can you post a screenshot or live example?

Comment: Yeah, it also don't seem aligned left to me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLIKt

Comment: is there any css for the `rounded` class?

Answer (score 2):

If you put a constraint on your body, the div will only center within that.

The width/height should be set on the div, not the body.

```
body {
background-image: url('stjohnhusimages/green gradient.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
text-align:center;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tqT6W/1/)

Answer (score 0):

is not necessary to have a fixed width size to the body, if the body is fixed width the inner div will not center and will depend on the size of it.

For the div is centered should remove the fixed width of the body

```
body {
background-image: url('stjohnhusimages/green gradient.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
text-align:center;
}
```